# What's the difference between Frost Walker I and Frost Walker II?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I got Frost Walker I when I enchanted some leather boots, and now I got Frost Walker II from fishing and added it to different leather boots that did not originally have Frost Walker. I used them on water and can I say I cannot tell a difference between I and II.

So what are the differences between the two enchantments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Frost_Walker):

> If moving on ground (i.e. not falling, jumping, or flying), any still water blocks with air above **within a radius of 2 + Level** around the block being moved to will be turned into frosted ice.

Answer (score 1):

Frost walker II has a farther water freeze radius. Frost walker I has a shorter water freeze radius. So in other words, frost walker II, which is slightly better than FW I, will freeze water blocks farther away.